# Special Style for TabItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles, tabitem

Can anyone help me with style on WPF. I am trying to make something like on screenshot. I don`t understand how to make borders of TabItemHeader and TabItemContent like that.

[image: Screenshot]

Updated:

I have make something like that: http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=2fd7604dd85877a6d7fa625de9439d7a
But the last problem is Border of content. How to set thickness of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" />
```

Comment: Where I should to place it?

Comment: just add a `BorderThickness` property to your `Border` tag in the style